# On Angular Js grid I want dropdownlist ,textbox and radiobutton

Tags: angularjs, grid

```
$scope.gridOptions={data:'test',
ColumnDefs:[
DisplayName:'Select Gender',
field:'Gender',
CellTemplate:'<div><input type='text'></div>' ]};
```

within cell template I want dropdown,textbox and radio button

Answer (score 0):

For TextBox on Grid-cellTemplate:''